# Open source cloud virtual server software

Tags: open-source, cloud

I am looking for an open source virtual server cloud framework library. If there is anything like this, I plan to start my own sort of simple Amazon EC2-like service (I have the hardware, I need to make or obtain the software). I apologize if this is a ridiculous question, but if it is, please point me in the right direction.

Thank you, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Yeah, there is this great website called google. You should check it out. http://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+cloud+software

Comment: This is an undertaking that took companies like Amazon, Google, Microsoft, and many others years to wrap their heads around. I don't think it's feasible to expect a useful answer here.

Comment: Agreed, but I cant believe people are down voting.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that Ubuntu has something called Eucalyptus : http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are talking about virtualization. Look in to [Xen](http://www.xen.org/). There are a few vps hosting places that use it. I have a vps on xen hvm and have had a great experience so far.